# Converting arraylist of custom class to JSONArray

Tags: android, arrays

I didn't expect this is that complex. But I can't figure out how I can convert my arraylist of custom class to a JSONArray. I understand there is no direct method to do that. So I made arraylist of JSONObjects from my arraylist. Now in order to save this into a JSON file, how can I convert the arraylist of JSONObjects to JSONArray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
JSONArray toReturn = new JSONArray();
for(JSONObject object : yourJSONArrayList){
    toReturn.put(object);
}
```

toReturn will then be a JSONArray that has all the JSONObjects from your arraylist of JSONObjects in it.

Comment: Laughing at myself... As a old .NET developer, I searched add or insert. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Give [Gson Library](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) a try, all that custom json conversion code goes away.

Comment: I thought about it before but since our app has relatively large file size, I didn't want to add another 200K. But thanks anyway.